# Ionic App I've been having this issue for quite some time now is it a permissions issue?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase

After logging in to the app I want to bind to profile(front end) data (username and email) to front end. But this doesn't work. Is there anything I'm doing wrong here?

```js
$scope.login = function() {
  fbref.$authWithPassword({
    email: $scope.email,
    password: $scope.password
  }).then(function(authData) {
    $scope.userprofile = authData;
    $state.go('tabsController.pendingTasks');
  })
}
```

```html
<div ng-controller="loginCtrl" class="card" ng-show="user">
  <div class="item item-divider">Username: {{userprofile.email}}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  </div>
  <div class="item item-text-wrap">
    {{userprofile.password.email}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't $authWithPassword be authWithPassword?  I'm not a firebase guy but a quick search turned this up https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/authwithpassword.html

Comment: i've used $authWithPassword and it works. i'm just not able to bind on front end.

Comment: So $scope.userprofile is getting assigned properly?  If so, you are going to need to share more of your code with us, preferably a plunker or jsfiddle.

Comment: its an ionic app will it run on jsfiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=qmViCoNoFw

Comment: i've shared a link to my jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using cacheProfile worked pretty well. eg $scope.cachedProfile = authData.google.cachedUserProfile;
$scope.cachedProfile.password = $scope.cachedProfile.uid;
$scope.profileImage = authData.google.profileImageURL;

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation the success callback returns an object with fields uid, provider, auth, and expires. Put a breakpoint inside that callback or log it like to the console.

https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/authwithpassword.html

```
console.log('authData', authData);
```

Comment: ok that makes sense but how can i pass the data on the front end before it expires. so i can be to bind it

Comment: check the value of authData.auth

Comment: i've tried this thing with pouchdb it still ddnt work, im thinking the problem could be with routing. when implementing $state.go(); somehow the data is lost.

Comment: I doubt pouchdb has anything to do with it. Make sure you call $scope.$apply() in your callback to trigger a digest cycle.